# Using VBA code to change range in formula if it has a certain range

Tags: excel, if-statement, replace, vba

I have a code that I'm working on to update a sheet that pulls information from another that has 12 columns of data based on the months of the year. The sheet that is being updated and that pulls the data from the other sheet only needs the current and previous months information. I know that this can be accomplished by finding and replacing the column letters to the current months and previous months column, but I'm trying to write VBA so that it will do it automatically upon open or by using a command button.

I'm using the if function to check what month is the data currently showing, but the if function isn't picking it up.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'
' Button1_Click Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
'

Dim current As String
current = Range("B8")

If current = "=+'Trend Balance Sheet'!$W$9" Then

Range("B:B").Value = Range("C:C").Value
Range("F:F").Value = Range("G:G").Value

Worksheets("Balance Sheet").Columns("B").Replace _
  What:="$W", Replacement:="$L", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
Worksheets("Balance Sheet").Columns("F").Replace _
  What:="$W", Replacement:="$L", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Dim OriginalT As String
Dim CorrectedT As String

OriginalText = Range("B5")

CorrectedT = Replace(OriginalT, "12/31/15", "01/31/16")

Range("B5") = CorrectedT

ElseIf current = "=+'Trend Balance Sheet'!$L$9" Then

Range("B:B").Copy Range("C:C") 
Range("F:F").Copy Range("G:G")

Dim OText As String
Dim CText As String
OText = Range("B5")
CText = Replace(OText, "01/31/16", "02/28/16")
Range("B5") = CText

Worksheets("Balance Sheet").Columns("B").Replace _
  What:="L", Replacement:="M", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
Worksheets("Balance Sheet").Columns("F").Replace _
  What:="L", Replacement:="M", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End If

     Application.Goto Reference:="Button1_Click"

End Sub
```

Comment: Here are some things to get you started: (1) start coding **explicitly**. Instead of `current = Range("B8")` state the excel file and the sheet you are referring to by using `current = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B8")` (2) use `Option Explicit` that will help you see another problem, notably that you are sometimes using `OriginalText` and sometimes `OriginalT`. Yet, I believe that both are meant to address the same variable (3) please insert a comment in your code where you have a problem / error / bug. To me, it is not clear yet what the problem is and **where** in the code it is.